# Uncaught Invariant Violation : Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am just fiddling with react-native and trying to build a mock up with a simple navigation. However , I am stuck at a point where I have no clue about the reason causing this.

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => App);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Routes from './src/config/routes';

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Routes/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Routes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import Home from '../screens/Home';
import SignUp from '../screens/SignUp';

export default const Routes = StackNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: Home },
        SignUp: { screen: SignUp },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        headerMode: "none",
    }
);
```

Error :

[image: This is what i get after running react-native run android]

Comment: As the 'unexpected token' error would suggest, you have a syntax error in your `routes.js`. You've not wrapped your list in square brackets.

Comment: @JoeClay I have included the routes in app.js . Still I get the first error. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would be helpful. but please try to check it as following:

1. please correct file name on App.js like this:
   `import Routes from './src/config/Routes';`
   as above your code, your file name should be Routes, not routes.
2. on Routes.js, please try to do as following:

   `export default const Routes = StackNavigator({
     initialRouteName: Home,
     Home: { screen: Home },
     SignUp: { screen: SignUp },
   },
   {
     headerMode: "none",
   });`

Comment: This doesnt help.